# Test point inside a polygon

Tags: java, android, polygon

I'm trying to test if a point is insde a polygon o not, and looking in SO. i found some codes that does it, but I tried, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

I got to Vectors to save x and y points:

```
Vector<Double> vxpoints;
Vector<Double> vxpoints;
```

thats my method "contains"

```
public boolean contains(double x, double y) {       
    int i,j = this.npoints - 1;  
    boolean oddNodes = false;  

    for(i=0;i<this.npoints;j=i++) {
        if ((((this.vypoints.get(i) <= y) && (y < this.vypoints.get(j))) ||
                ((this.vypoints.get(j) <= y) && (y < this.vypoints.get(i)))) &&
                (x < (this.vxpoints.get(j) - this.vxpoints.get(i)) * (y - this.vypoints.get(i)) / (this.vypoints.get(j) - this.vypoints.get(i)) + this.vxpoints.get(i)))
            oddNodes = !oddNodes;
    }   
    return oddNodes;
```

And when I test it, I do with "easy polygons":
 (There are to arrays os points, that I convert in vectors inside my class)

```
    double xpoints[] = {100,100,200,200}; //Square      
    double ypoints[] = {100,200,100,200};
    PolygonDouble test = new PolygonDouble(xpoints, ypoints);

    //System.out.println(test.getNumberOfCoordinates());
    if(test.contains(110,110))
        System.out.println("Inside");
    else
        System.out.println("Outside");
```

Output: --> Outside
but if I try with the point (110,111) the Output --> Inside.

I don't kwow what's going on..... :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of your square used in your test. The vertices are the wrong order. Change the order of the third and fourth vertex and it the test should work.

```
double xpoints[] = {100,100,200,200}; //Square      
double ypoints[] = {100,200,200,100};
```

Comment: Changed and worked, and tested with other "easy" polygon.

So, if I dont understand bad... That means that the code it's correct, but I have to define the order of the points in Clock order?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the polygon is in clockwise or counter clockwise order. However, it does matter that your 'rectangle' is twisted into a bow-tie shape (so it's not really a rectangle) because of the order of your vertices.

Comment: It's no because of clockwise or counter clockwise. You crossed two lines of the square. When at Test fails there are three options: your code under test is wrong, the test itself is wrong or both are wrong :-)

Comment: (1/2)
Well, with this "easy" polygons know is working. 
Now, other problem. All I done for this, it's because I have to read KML file, extract the coordinates, and then test if a point is inside this coordinates.
I do all of that. so the coordinates of my KML file looks like that:
    <....>
    <coordinates>      2.190381090601514,41.40432338788778,0 2.193329807442894,41.40506539312711,0 2.193393168346678,41.40527938280415,0 2.191414958783979,41.40665429357642,0 2.189340368185269,41.4050514432114,0 2.190381090601514,41.40432338788778,0 </coordinates>

Comment: (2/2) and when i process it and save in Vectors, those vectors look like that:

`Vx:[2.190381090601514, 2.193329807442894, 2.193393168346678,2.191414958783979, 2.189340368185269, 2.190381090601514]

    Vy:[41.40432338788778, 41.40506539312711, 41.40527938280415, 41.40665429357642, 41.4050514432114, 41.40432338788778]
Test2: Outside
And the tested point:

    test.contains(2.191680866734278,41.40505441788871) (Suposed to be inside!!)
    Test2: Outside`